# Converting ms-access database into easy to use spatial database

Tags: qgis, database, ms-access, accdb

I've recently come into ownership of an MS-Access database (2007 accdb), which I want to be able to use in a GIS. I know a little bit about GIS (I've used QGIS and ArcGIS quite a bit) but very little about databases. There is currently no spatial data in it but I do have various shapefiles which I want to link it to and ideally merge all these files/databases into one spatial database.

If I had access to ArcMAP I'd probably just set up an ESRI Geodatabase, but that's not available. From what I've read PostGIS might be something I could use but as I say I know very little about databases beyond MS-Access.

Is there a user friendly system someone could point me in the direction of? It would need to be compatible with MapInfo 7 (don't ask!) or QGIS. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to keep your geometry in shapefiles and keep the data in access. Just make sure there is a common ID in both tables. Both QGIS and Mapinfo support joining shapes to database features (eg accessed via odbc). In Mapinfo, check the function "geocode".

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I've done what you've suggested and it works fine. The table is quite large - is there anyway to avoid it impacting on performance in QGIS on what is a fairly elderly laptop?

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in PostGIS, you might want to visit the BostonGIS website. They have great [material to get you started](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01#304). You can also start with OpenGeo's [introduction to PostGIS workshop](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/).

PostGIS has a [shapefile importer](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) that you can use to load your shape files. As for your accdb files, you might want to convert them to SQL first. Bullzip has this free [tool for converting accdb files to SQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2p/info.php) and loading them to Postgresql/PostGIS. Once loaded, you can then join them in PostGIS.

QGIS has [native PostGIS support](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Database). [Mapinfo supports PostGIS](http://li.pbbiblogs.com/2009/04/28/mapinfo-professional-v100-support-for-postgis/), too.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply - those beginner guides were exactly what I was looking for!